# Dialog vs hidden/shown layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

If you have  an activity and you need to display some sort of square overlay which has buttons. Why would you use dialog over nested layout with setVisibility ?or vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a nested layout, you'd need to put all the logic for what's going on in that 'dialog', into the Activity as well. On the other hand, if you have a dialog you can put that logic in that separate class, which makes it easier to reuse it elsewhere (think DatePickerDialog etc.) Also, when showing a dialog, the system automatically does the work of shading down and blocking the rest of the UI, handling of back button functionality etc.

But in general, you can also use a nested layout instead of a dialog. You can also overcome some above mentioned shortcomings by implementing a custom view and putting your dialog logic there.

Comment: So I guess the main 2 separators are, with dialog it is better encapsulated as separate code. But with nested layout you get the ability to interact with the background activity as well while dialog is showing

Comment: You can also interact with the background activity from a real dialog(fragment) via listeners (same as with normal fragments) but it requires more boilerplate code.